# How to put all lines starting with a specific character combination on the previous line in Excel or Notepad++?

Tags: excel, csv, notepad++

I'm trying to import the following [CSV](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/I2CZQY) data set into Excel. I'm using the Text Import Wizard to set the right delimiters. So far, I used the ";" and "," delimiters.

Here is the [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jn5rGfaAppwwCSF__uyHaB5ca_hCvzqh/view?usp=sharing) so far. The data set seems to be looking fine, until row 493. From that point on, the data changes from the year 2014 to 2015. Somehow, the format of the data seems to have changed somewhat from that point on, resulting in a CSV file in which the columns are not aligned anymore.

Here's a snapshot of what happens in Notepad++ (which allows one to see the exact characters in the document more clearly):

[image]

I've already asked about this problem over [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1607057/what-is-going-wrong-with-importing-and-formatting-the-following-csv-data-set-in), but so far that question has not yielded a solution. I've also considered taking up the advice in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1560950/how-to-move-the-next-line-starting-with-move-to-previous-line-end-in-notepad) Super User SE question, but I think I can't apply it in this situation because the character combination to use is “**",**”, and Notepad++ does not seem to recognize `\R(?="";")` in the document.

I'm now considering to solve this problem by putting lines starting with the “**",**” character combination on the previous line.

**Question**: what should I do to format this CSV data set in such a way that all rows starting with “**",**” are put on their respective previous lines? (Either in Notepad++ or Excel.)

*Note*: [cross-post](https://superuser.com/questions/1607327/how-to-put-all-lines-starting-with-a-specific-character-combination-on-the-previ) from Super User SE.

Comment: You are import a csv file into excel? And then the picture is what it looks like after the import? And you want the lines starting with " to be on the previous line?

Comment: @NicholasStom Answers to your respective questions: 1) Yes. 2.) Nope, the picture is of an import of the csv in Notepad++ . I also used this program, because I thought it could be useful for the task at hand as well. 3.) I want the lines starting with ", to begin on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

We can work from the bottom upwards.  First import the `.CSV` into column **A** only *(do no parsing)* For example:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub FixTheData()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, LookFor As String
    
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LookFor = Chr(34) & Chr(44)
    
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        If Left(v, 2) = LookFor Then
            Cells(i - 1, "A").Value = Cells(i - 1, "A").Value & v
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

The result:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the macro from the Excel window:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I inquire where I should put the code in Excel?

Comment: @MaxMuller  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you! I suppose those alt codes are suitable for the windows environment? I'm working on a mac - e.g. it doesn not seem to open up the VBE window with the ALT-F11

Comment: @MaxMuller  Can you open the ***VBE*** from the Ribbon Menus ???

Comment: Yes, I've managed to generate the macro. Unfortunately, is does not seem to do what it intended. Here's a screen shot of what the Excel file looks like now in the first two columns: https://i.postimg.cc/659GTzX9/Screenshot-2020-12-04-at-18-10-11.jpg